# Get reports on spending from Amazon?

Tags: budget, online, amazon

Supposedly I can get a report on my spending on Amazon. For example, this [web page describes going to Orders & Lists / Preferences / Reports](https://knowtechie.com/this-simple-trick-shows-you-how-much-money-youve-wasted-shopping-on-amazon-2/), but when I go to the same place there is no option for ordering reports. Here is what my screen looks like:

[image]

As you can see there is no option for ordering reports. So, what is going on? How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to an [article on doctorofcredit.com](https://www.doctorofcredit.com/amazon-to-sunset-order-history-reports-after-march-20th/) and [this reddit post on r/DataHoarder](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/11kbuta/amazon_order_history_reports_ending_march_20_2023/), Amazon's Order Reports feature, where you could get a list of your orders in a spreadsheet format, was discontinued on March 20, 2023.  Your order history is still available for viewing on amazon.com, but it is much more cumbersome to deal with.

What you can do, however, is visit Amazon's [Request My Data](https://www.amazon.com/gp/privacycentral/dsar/preview.html) page, which allows you to request different types of data from your account (including "Your Orders"), and they will send it to you in a downloadable format.

Alternatively, there is a Chrome browser extension called [Amazon Order History Reporter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-order-history-repo/mgkilgclilajckgnedgjgnfdokkgnibi) that will put your Amazon Order History in a CSV file for you. (I have no experience with it.)

Comment: While not as extensive as a CSV file, you can also view past orders under My Account -> Payments -> Transactions. This list is MUCH easier to quickly skim through that the main "My Orders" page.